# code is putting all numbers in one box when i need it split across 3

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with 40 `checkboxes` each one referring to a single  card from that form I need to take them and put them into the table I have set up with the headings

```
name card1 card2 card3 date
```

The code I have is  instead of putting  the card numbers across 3 columns, all the numbers are going into  into one column which is resulting in an error with incorrect number of columns

to visually demonstrate what I mean

How its doing it now

```
Name     card1   card2    card3   date
---------------------------------------
myname     1         2      3
```

what I need is

```
Name     card1   card2    card3   date
----------------------------------------
myname   1        2         3    (date)
```

here is my code I have now and will show you how it echos as well

```
$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['whatcard']);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
echo $query="INSERT INTO earlyreg 
(name, card1, card2, card3, date) VALUES ('playernick', '" . $checkBox . "',  CURRENT_DATE())";mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
```

This si the echo I get

`INSERT INTO earlyreg (name, card1, card2, card3, date) VALUES ('playernick', ' . 5,6,7 . ', CURRENT_DATE())`

Error message

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: You should use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables. I hope you're using mysqli or PDO, not mysql, so you can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $query="INSERT INTO earlyreg (name, card1, card2, card3, date) VALUES ('playernick', " . $checkBox . ",  CURRENT_DATE())";mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
```

Remove the single quotes around `$checkbox` . It seems like a slightly insecure way of doing it though.